# I can't figure out how it is possible to find a logical expression that is logically equivalent to ~(p iff q) without using and?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPydP.png)

I have shown the first part of the question by using a material equivalence to convert the (p iff q) to

(p and q) or (not p and not q)

and then applying DeMorgan's Law a couple times with the not on the outside. But I'm stumped and have no idea how to start on using that expression to create one that is L.E but only uses not and or? If you take out the and then there's no way it can be a biconditional anymore right?

Comment: Hint: replace $a\land b$ by $\lnot(\lnot a\lor\lnot b)$.

Comment: I was looking for something to replace the and but I must have missed something... What does that derive from?

Comment: Another thing you can do with $(p \lor q) \land (\neg p \lor \neg q)$ is distribute $\land$ over $\lor$ and eliminate contradictions to obtain $(p \land \neg q) \vee (\neg p \land q)$. Then apply the first comment.

Answer (score 1):

$$\neg (\neg (p \vee q) \vee \neg (\neg p \vee  \neg q)) $$
is L.E to $\neg (p \iff q)$.